# Why is my sorting method in qsort changing my array?

Tags: c, qsort

https://phoxis.org/2012/07/12/get-sorted-index-orderting-of-an-array/

I tried the method here under the section

Using qsort in C

to sort an array and return the indices, changing the array base_arr to be of type double*. However, when I print the arr[idx[i]] to the screen, half of the values have been changed to 0 and have been sorted as if they had always been 0. What could cause this to happen?

```
double *BASE_ARR;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int N = par->N;
int K = par->K;
double *ptr;
ptr = (double *) malloc(N*sizeof(ptr)); 

int *idx;
idx = (int *) malloc(N*sizeof(idx));

// generate the array to be sorted (ptr), in a separate file

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    idx[i] = i;
}

BASE_ARR = ptr; 
// sort
qsort(idx, N, sizeof(idx), idxSort);


for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("%f\n",ptr[idx[i]]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("%d\n",idx[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
    idx[i] = -1;
}


return 0;
}

static int idxSort (const void *a, const void *b) {
int aa = *((int *)a), bb = *((int *)b);

if (BASE_ARR[aa] < BASE_ARR[bb]) {
    return -1;
}
if (BASE_ARR[aa] == BASE_ARR[bb]) {
    printf("what");tack
    return 0;
}
if (BASE_ARR[aa] > BASE_ARR[bb]) {
    return 1;
}

}
```

Comment: You malloc the wrong amount of space. the `sizeof` expression should be measuring the size of what you are pointing to, not the size of a pointer

Answer (score 2):

```
qsort(idx, N, sizeof(idx), idxSort);
```

should be

```
qsort(idx, N, sizeof(*idx), idxSort);
```

`idx` is a pointer. `qsort` doesn't need to know the size of a pointer; it needs to know the size of the array element.

Same about your `malloc` calls. You need to use `sizeof(*idx)` and `sizeof(*ptr)` in them. By the way, do not cast the result of `malloc`.