# Sort an array by the index with the largest value using qsort in C

Tags: arrays, c, indexing, qsort

i need sort an array as follows:

`int *array = malloc(5*sizeof(int))`

Let's say array = [2, 4, 1, 3, 2]

```
     index   0 1  2  3   4
```

I have to order it so that the index that has the highest value is at the beginning and so on in decreasing order

so the output has to be

array  = [1 , 3, 0, 4, 2] or [1 , 3, 4, 0, 2] (no matters because index 0 and 4 have the same value)

I know that using qsort i can order for value doing this:

```
    int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) { 
    
       return (*(int*)b -  *(int*)a );
    }


   qsort(array, 5, sizeof(u32), cmpfunc);
```

but the output of this one will be:

array = [4,3,2,2,1]

Comment: Sorting means rearranging the elements of an array in a certain way, which is not what you are asking to do here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938358/why-is-my-sorting-method-in-qsort-changing-my-array)

Comment: You could look up `qsort_r()`, but beware that it is not standardized by POSIX, probably because the Linux and BSD interfaces to `qsort_r()` are incompatible in a number of crucial ways.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not sort the values but sort the indices.

You start with the array of values, then create an array where the values are the current index number.

Then in your sorting function, the values you get are the indices into the original array.  So then use those values to index the original array and then compare those values.

```
int order[] = {2, 4, 1, 3, 2};

int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const int *a = p1, *b = p2;
    return order[*b] - order[*a];
}

int main()
{
    int idx[] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    qsort(idx,5,sizeof(int), cmp);
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
        printf("%d\n", idx[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This example uses fixed arrays, but it's simple to adapt it to use dynamically allocated arrays.

Output:

```
1
3
0
4
2
```